# MYSQL select с интервалами времени

Tags: mysql, дата, select

Добрый день! Помогите, пожалуйста, оптимизировать запрос. Нужно сделать выборку с интервалом по часу например, из таблицы со звонками телефонными по времени. Вот как-то делать неправильно и некрасиво..

```
SELECT
SUM(call_result = 10 and entire_call = 1 and time(dt_tm) between '04:00%' and '05:00%') AS Принятые_4-5,
SUM(call_result = 10 and entire_call = 1 and time(dt_tm) between '05:00%' and '06:00%') AS Принятые_5-6,
SUM(call_result = 10 and entire_call = 1 and time(dt_tm) between '07:00%' and '08:00%') AS Принятые_7-8,
SUM(call_result = 8 and time(dt_tm) between '04:00%' and '05:00%') AS Пропущенные_4-5,
SUM(call_result = 8 and time(dt_tm) between '04:00%' and '05:00%') AS Пропущенные_5-6


FROM BD
where (num ='1234' or num = '5678')
and dt_tm BETWEEN '2017-11-20%' AND '2017-12-02%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Я так понимаю, что надо подсчитать кол-во звонков за каждый час?

Как бы я делал:

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(num)
FROM
    BD
WHERE
    (num ='1234' OR num = '5678') AND
    (dt_tm BETWEEN '2017-11-20%' AND '2017-12-02%)
GROUP BY
    CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_tm), ...);
```

Я не стал расписывать условие

```
CONCAT(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_tm), ...);
```

Ты можешь это сделать самостоятельно (просто придется по помощи по mysql поползать чуть-чуть)

Основная цель этого условия превратить твою dt_tm в некоторую конструкцию, которая будет уникальна для всех времен с точностью до часу, например

```
ГОД МЕСЯЦ ДЕНЬ ЧАС
```

**P.S.**

все таки влез в помощь :)

```
CONCAT_WS(EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_tm), EXTRACT(YEAR FROM dt_tm), EXTRACT(MONTH FROM dt_tm), EXTRACT(DAY FROM dt_tm), EXTRACT(HOUR FROM dt_tm))
```

В итоге для текущего времени написания этого ответа будет сформирована строка

> 2017 11 29 13

**P.P.S.**

Возможно стоит написать так

```
SELECT 
    IFNULL(COUNT(num), 0) AS count
```

*Проверил - COUNT всегда выдаёт число, поэтому IFNULL не требуется, таким образом*

```
SELECT 
    COUNT(num) AS count
```

Comment: думаете `count` может возвращать `null` что ли? это другие агрегаты могут так делать, поскольку находят значение или считаю на их основе, а эта считает количество, поэтому при отсутствии данных вернет 0.

Comment: не был уверен - поэтому написал, тогда просто COUNT оставить

Comment: а не проще ли вместо гигантской строчки с кучей `extract` написать `DATE_FORMAT(dt_tm, '%Y%m%d%H')` ? И всё же корректнее эту конструкцию вынести в конструкцию SELECT, дать ей alias и в GROUP BY указать уже его.

Comment: Александр, как говорится "за ваши деньги любой каприз". Ваш пример приятнее моего, думаю его и надо использовать, поскольку он нагляднее. Впрочем общая идея передана - группировать по некоторой конструкции, которая одинакова для даты с точностью до часа.